Is it possible to specifically handle Hudi exceptions in Pyspark
I am reading Hudi tables from s3 and sometimes the bucket or prefix may be empty and  org.apache.hudi.exception.TableNotFoundException is thrown. is there a way for me to import and handle these specific errors instead of the generic Exception in my try/except block?
i am on spark 3.4.1 and hudi 0.14

Yeah, It should be do able. First import the expected Exception.
from org.apache.hudi.exception import TableNotFoundException

Use it in the try except statement.
try:
    if bucket_or_prefix_empty:
        raise TableNotFoundException("Bucket or prefix is empty")
except TableNotFoundException as e:
    print("Table not found:", e)
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

